# Inline PHP code for math calculation before import with WP ALL Import

Tags: php, wordpress, inline, wpallimport

Currently, I am facing a problem with import where I need to write a custom inline PHP code for this.
I have many numbers, for example, 0.001, 0.104, 0.302
I would like to import only this

- if number is 0 to 0.100 - import "good"
- if is 0.101 to 0.200 - write "medium"
- if is 0.201 and more - write "bad"

I already use this PHP code for calculating the number written above.

```
function my_math($param1,$param2){
    return number_format($param1/$param2,3);}
```

thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
// This function uses guard clause to return a string
function my_math($param1, $param2) {
    
    // Set number variable to check if statements on
    $num = number_format($param1 / $param2, 3);

    // Return "bad" if above .2
    if ($num > .2)
        return "bad";

    // Return "good" if below .1    
    if ($num < .1)
        return "good";

    // Default return if none of the above 
    return "medium";
}
```

Edit: added documentation and extra snippet

---

As asked here's an example without the $num variable

```html
function my_math($input) {

    if ($input > .2)
        return "bad";

    if ($input < .1)
        return "good";

    return "medium";
}
```

Comment: Hi @xtv369 perfect. It works really. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: perhaps you can help me also with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70084673/replace-url-to-text-if-url-contains-some-names

Comment: How it would look without the calculation  $num = number_format($param1 / $param2, 3)? Only compare "more", "less", ... of simple number

Comment: Hi @MichalKovalčík, your other question looks deleted. To get a result without the number_format, something like this should do 
`function my_math($input) {
    
    if ($input > .2)
        return "bad";
    
    if ($input < .1)
        return "good";

    return "medium";
}`

Comment: thank you @xtv369. looks good